# Where is the file that notifies you when you have low battery?

Tags: windows-8, battery, notifications

Does anyone know where the file is located that displays the low battery warning on Windows 8? [image: http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/15-10-2012-12-27-52-400x78.jpg?bbdc8f]

I've searched the entire `system32` folder but I can't find it there, maybe it's part of another program?

Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: This is probably an exe or something...

Comment: Ah, as far as what displays the window - the simplest answer is "part of the system". I would *guess* at it being part of the shell (Explorer). Is there any particular reason you need to know? Note that this would all be undocumented, not guaranteed, and could potentially change at any time MS feels like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power supply unit is responsible for the battery usage details. These files are hidden files. We need to generate the report manually. Please follow the below steps,

1) Open Command Prompt

2) use the command the below command

powercfg /batteryreport /output "C:\Full Path\battery_report.html"

3. Double click/tap on the battery_report.html file on your desktop to open and see your battery usage report in your default web browser.
4. This is a copy of my laptop's battery usage report in Internet Explorer as an example of what is reported.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but helpful nonetheless.